# Return the position clicked in recyclerview in a different Activity?

Tags: android, onclick, position, android-recyclerview

I have a recylcerview in a navigation drawer and I wish to find what position was clicked by the user in the recyclerview in a different activity. The way I have written the code currently always return 0 as the position. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance!

Recyclerview in Navigation drawer code:

```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    adapter = new NavigationDrawerFragmentAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView,new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            if (position == 0){

            }
            if (position == 27){

            }
            if (position == 28){

            }
            if (position == 29){

            }
            if (position ==30){

            }
            else{
            test.getPositionClicked(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Test.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
        }
    }));
    return layout;
}
```

And My Activity code where I wish to find the position clicked:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Toast is working " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (pos == 1){
        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Accounting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void getPositionClicked(int position) {
    position = pos;
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass data in a bundle and add it to the intent of the new activity.

// onClick at recycler

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(context, Other_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("SOME_ID", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

//Second activity

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
    int position = extras.getInt("SOME_ID");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to pass position to the activity, that you're starting. Then you can pass the value of position to the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Test.class);
i.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(i);
```

And then in your Test activity you retrieve the value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) position = extras.getInt("position", 0);
}
```